# Python Pandas, change table to percentages rather than individual results

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to make my table show percentages rather than individual data, but I cannot get it to work:

```
p_table = pd.pivot_table(df, index='party',columns='negotiated',fill_value=0, aggfunc='size')
p_table
```

This is what I get:
[image: Results of table]

Answer (score 4):

#### `crosstab`

has a `normalize` option

```
pd.crosstab(df.party, df.negotiated, normalize=True)
```